# ASP.Net Control.ResolveUrl quirks

Tags: asp.net

I have a weird issue. 
When resolving urls for script elements, the src element must be in ' '. With link elements the href must be in " ", or the code nugget gets rendered into html for some reason. The code snippet below illustrates the problem more clearly. Why is this the case?

```
<script src='<%:Page.ResolveUrl("~/JavaScript/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.js") %>' type="text/javascript"/>

<link href="<%:Page.ResolveUrl("~/CSS/Foundation/foundation.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

**Edit**
Just noticed the script element src tag works fine when enclosed in " " or ' ', but the link element href tag only seems to work when enclosed in " ".

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are using a <kbd>:</kbd> in your script.  Instead, you should do this (and it will work using single quotes as well as double quotes:

```
<link href="<%= ResolveUrl("~/Styles/site.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Observe above that I used a <kbd>=</kbd> rather than a <kbd>:</kbd>

Or, in some situations you can even use the <kbd>#</kbd> if you, say, called `Page.Header.DataBind();` in the codebehind of a masterpage and you are outputing your references in the `<head>` of your masterpage:

```
<link href="<%# ResolveUrl("~/Styles/site.css")%>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: I had already tried the '<%=' option and it doesn't work either. The ':' vs '=' seems to be irrelevant in my case.

Comment: I just tried it and it does work :).  And to boot, I tried using the single quotes using your colon, and it DID NOT work as expected.  So, change your : to a = (make sure you get the syntax correct) and you are golden.

Comment: I did not call page.header.databind(), but the # does work with single quotes. I don't know why though.

Comment: I checked again, and the = still works with double quotes only in my case. I am using a web appl. project with IIS express, maybe that has something to do with it.

Comment: Interesting, I've looked it over to be sure, and = works just fine.  Well, go with what works, and either use the # with single quotes, or use : with double quotes (though I must admit, I've never seen the : used before in that manner).